# Can a query write to the binary log BEFORE it has finished executing?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, log

I have a Database which is a Slave and a Master. e.g. it replicates data from our main site, and then onwards to a set of slave databases. (this is mainly a test facility so not monitored out of hours).

On Sunday morning at 7:55 it started executing an `INSERT` query. This is a standard query that executes thousands of times a day. Its a single query, not part of a transaction. There are no triggers on that table. This table (and all others) are `INNODB`.

But, on this occasion it got stuck. When I came in the office today it had been running for 24 hours (apparently). And replication was a day behind.

However, when I looked in the Binary logs it showed as `COMMIT`ed.

```
#160814  7:55:25 server id 21  end_log_pos 103319397    Query   thread_id=635785334 exec_time=4294967294    error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1471157725/*!*/;
INSERT INTO tablename . . . 
/*!*/;
# at 103319397
#160814  7:55:25 server id 21  end_log_pos 103319424    Xid = 284047583
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 103319424
```

I checked the Slave databases, and it was on present on there as you'd expect.

I have a monitoring system which records (amongst other things) the processlist, and it shows that for that `INSERT` query it was perpetually stuck at `STATE = UPDATE`.

I also checked the `slow query log` to see if it was in there, and it wasn't.

My understanding was that a query couldn't be written to the `binary log` until it was `commmited` on the master, so can anyone explain what has happenned here?

There was a knock on affect in that once out test system tried to connect at 8:38 this morning, the first `SELECT` query also got stuck, and then it refused all connetions. So I was forced to restart the database.
At which point it ran crash recovery, and carried on as if nothing had happenned.

It is MySQL 5.5.47 and using Statement Based Replication.

Comment: Was `autocommit` on when you performed the `INSERT`?

Comment: The slowlog is not written until the query finishes.

Comment: 4294967294 = 2^32-2 -- that is, `-2` stored in `INT UNSIGNED`.  I have seen things like that before, but without figuring out enough to file a bug report.

Comment: you could be on to something there. 4294967294 = 1,193,046 hours!! It was only 24 hours behind. Also looking at the binlog above, and indeed at least 3 before, they all had `exec_time=4294967294` for ALL queries. I'll need to see how far back this goes. Current logs are fine. (and `autocommit=1`).

Comment: OK, the exec_time of 4294967294 is due to the [Linux] slaves clock running  2 seconds slower than the [windows] master. Thus the queries seemed to be executing on the slave before the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting conflicting info from different sources, use the official documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

> Binary logging is done immediately after a statement or transaction completes but before any locks are released or any commit is done. This ensures that the log is logged in commit order.

This means there is a narrow window in which a failure could cause an uncommitted transaction to exist in the binary log but not in the database. This seems to be what has happened in your case.

> For example, if you are using InnoDB tables and the MySQL server processes a COMMIT statement, it writes the whole transaction to the binary log and then commits this transaction into InnoDB. If the server crashes between those two operations, the transaction is rolled back by InnoDB at restart but still exists in the binary log. To resolve this, you should set --innodb_support_xa to 1. Although this option is related to the support of XA transactions in InnoDB, it also ensures that the binary log and InnoDB data files are synchronized.

Comment: cheers for that. I use the official docs where I can but for reasons I haven't yet fathomed, random sections are blocked by our IT dept !?! This is one such section.

Comment: Fire your IT Dept ;-)

Answer (score 1):

well, it doesn't explain why the database locked up but it does answer part of my question:

> When a transaction is sent to a MySQL server running with binary
>   logging enabled, the transaction is executed normally, and **just prior
>   to completing the transaction the server records the change serially
>   in the binary log**. Once this is done, it tells the storage engine that
>   the transaction is ready to be committed.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/setting-mysql-replication-high-availability

---

Although, I've now just read the following:

The SQL statements are not

> The SQL statements are not
>   written into the binary log **until** the transaction commits,

which is from the 'Understanding MySQL Internals' book.

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote, it is important to understand the innodb_support_xa which is two phase commit model- statements are first prepared, and transaction cache is applied to binary log  in phase 1 -> in phase 2, once the trx is committed -> storage engine writes the prepared statments in safe storage/disk (depending on sync_binlog). After phase 2, locks on concerned table is released.

Note: transaction commit cannot be fail even if server crash after phase 1 since during recovery- the MySQL server tells InnoDB to complete any prepared transactions that were successfully written to the to the binary log, and truncates the binary log to the last valid position. This ensures that the binary log reflects the exact data of InnoDB tables, and therefore the slave remains in synchrony with the master because it does not receive a statement which has been rolled back.